# I can't seem to get the average of a list of numbers

Tags: ruby

```
print " Please enter a list of numbers "
numbers = eval(gets.chomp)
sum = numbers.reduce(:+)
print " The average is  " + sum.to_s / reduce.to_f
```

Comment: I can't seem to help you without more information; how is the result different than what you expected?

Comment: What is the error if any ? 
What is your input?

Comment: I am not able to get the average of a list of numbers i can only get the sum of the list of numbers

Comment: First write a program to compute average without reading input from console, by having hard coded values - once it is working, then, update the program to accept input from console.

Answer (score 2):

`sum.to_s` returns a string. You cannot divide a string by a float. And `reduce` is not even defined. You probably just want to use:

```
print " The average is  #{sum.to_f / numbers.size}"
```

Furthermore the use of `eval` is very dangerous in this context. Imagine what happens if someone enters something like `system('rm -rf /')`...

Comment: Let's hope that the OP is not going to try the latter.

Comment: @D56  Don't forget to click the tick icon and accept the answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

as Spickerman pointed out use of `eval` is very dangerous in this context so I would suggest you do something like

```
print " Please enter a list of numbers "
numbers = gets.strip.split(" ").map(&:to_f)
sum = numbers.reduce(:+)
print " The average is  #{sum/ numbers.size}"
```